# Google collections GWT jar

Tags: gwt, guava

Has anyone had any luck rolling a custom GWT jar for Google [Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) / [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)? I've tried uncommenting the relevant ant tasks and running them, but I just get empty folders in the JAR. Can't seem to get the include rules right :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that we intentionally don't provide this because the library does not work as it should on GWT. If you do it anyway, you might luck out, or you might not. We're working on this.

Comment: Yeah, I realize its still a work in progress... right now I just want to use some of the base classes like Precondition and Joiner - without copying them. Would it be possible to check in very light version into the trunk? Only the base classes and stuff thats guaranteed to work well.